# Eclipse show maven dependency bu class not found in content assist

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, spring-jdbc

My project structure like below

```
project_A
   |-pom.xml (depends on spring-jdbc 4.3.8.RELEASE)

Project_B
   |-pom.xml(depends on project_A)
   |-abstractDAOImpl - uses org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
```

I ca't access jdbctemplate class here jar is there in maven dependencies. I can see the class file but in open Type window i can't get this class. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found after some hit and try. Somehow my local repository was corrupted it seems. I closed the eclipse, deleted .m2/repository and build project again by command line `mvn clean compile install` and restarted the eclipse.now it's a charm...

Comment: If you do `mvn clean compile install` you are duplicating things a simple `mvn clean install` is enough. Take a deeper look into [Maven's life cycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)